# How can I loop Q&A sessions of a quiz game in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a Quiz game, following steps below

Step1. Read a CSV file to create a 2-D array.
Step2. From this 2-D array, the question and answers comprising of the wrong and the right.
Step3. JavaScript sets the Q&A on HTML elements.
Step4. When a user click the button element, JavaScript goes back to the Step1 through Step3.

Now, I got stuck with Step4, especially how to let Step1 work. Could you give me your advice?
Here are codes for each step.

Step1

```
let questionArea = document.getElementById("questions");
let answersArea = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
console.log(answersArea);


// Create a shift-jis-loading csv instance
let csv = new XMLHttpRequest();
csv.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=shift_jis");
 
// Open a csv file
csv.open("GET", "./csvfile/Word_List_1.csv", false);
 
// In case of failures of csv loading
try {
  csv.send(null);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
 
// Define an array
let csvArray = [];
 
// Process toward an Array csvArray
let lines = csv.responseText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
 
// Proceed with each line
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
  let cells = lines[i].split(",");
  if (cells.length != 1) {
    csvArray.push(cells);
  }
}

console.log(csvArray);
```

Step2

```
let randnum = Math.floor( Math.random() * csvArray.length);
let question = csvArray[randnum][0];
let correct = csvArray[randnum][1];
console.log(question);
console.log(correct);
console.log("上記がQA要素");

let fourOptions =[];
fourOptions.push(correct);

// Copy the csvArray
let cloneArray = structuredClone(csvArray);
// correctと被らないために両方の配列から消す処理
csvArray.splice(randnum,1);
cloneArray.splice(randnum,1);



// 選択肢できるまでwhile
let optionNum = 1;
console.log("while始まる");
let falseNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * csvArray.length);
while(optionNum<=answersArea.length-1){
  // console.log(falseNum);
  // console.log(cloneArray[falseNum][0]);
  // console.log(cloneArray[falseNum][1]);
  // 誤答を3つ入れる処理
  fourOptions.push(cloneArray[falseNum][1]);
  cloneArray.splice(falseNum,1);
  falseNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * cloneArray.length)
  optionNum = optionNum+1;
}
console.log("while終わった");

// For check on after false answers are selected
// console.log(csvArray);
// console.log(csvArray.length);



fourOptions = shuffle(fourOptions);
// Shuffle 1 right and 3 wrong answers by the below function
function shuffle(fourOptions) {
  const array = fourOptions.slice();
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[randomIndex]] = [array[randomIndex], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}
```

Step3

```
// SetQuiz
questionArea.textContent = question
let buttonNum = 0;
while(buttonNum<=answersArea.length-1){
  answersArea[buttonNum].textContent = fourOptions[buttonNum];
  buttonNum = buttonNum+1;
}
```

Step4

```
// Judge RIGHT or WRONG　and Next Q&A appears (Here is where I got stuck)
const $btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for(let i = 0; i < $btn.length; i++) {
  $btn[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{
  if(correct===$btn[i].textContent){
    console.log("GOOD！");
  }
  else{
    console.log("BAAAAAAD")
  }})
}
```

Any comments are welcome.
Currently I think of treat Step2 & Step3 as Function, but in that case, I don't know how to connect them with Step4.

UPDATED on 6/23 2023 JST

In STEP4, I could manage to change the Q&A sessions showing on the browser screen, but the procedure did not go well when judging RIGHT or WRONG from the second Q&A session onward:

The console.log("GOOD！"); or console.log("Not GOOD"); does not work.

Could you give an idea to let this process go well?

```
let SetQuiz = ()=>{
// 乱数設定＝＞英文と日本語を各々questionとcorrectへ入れる。
let randnum = Math.floor( Math.random() * csvArray.length);
let question = csvArray[randnum][0];
let correct = csvArray[randnum][1];
console.log(question);
console.log(correct);
console.log("上記がQA要素");

let fourOptions =[];
fourOptions.push(correct);

// Copy the csvArray
let cloneArray = structuredClone(csvArray);
// correctと被らないために両方の配列から消す処理
csvArray.splice(randnum,1);
cloneArray.splice(randnum,1);



// 選択肢できるまでwhile
let optionNum = 1;
console.log("while始まる");
let falseNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * csvArray.length);
while(optionNum<=answersArea.length-1){
  // console.log(falseNum);
  // console.log(cloneArray[falseNum][0]);
  // console.log(cloneArray[falseNum][1]);
  // 誤答を3つ入れる処理
  fourOptions.push(cloneArray[falseNum][1]);
  cloneArray.splice(falseNum,1);
  falseNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * cloneArray.length)
  optionNum = optionNum+1;
}
console.log("while終わった");

// For check on after false answers are selected
// console.log(csvArray);
// console.log(csvArray.length);



fourOptions = shuffle(fourOptions);
// Shuffle 1 right and 3 wrong answers by the below function
function shuffle(fourOptions) {
  const array = fourOptions.slice();
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[randomIndex]] = [array[randomIndex], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}

// SetQuiz
questionArea.textContent = question
let buttonNum = 0;
while(buttonNum<=answersArea.length-1){
  answersArea[buttonNum].textContent = fourOptions[buttonNum];
  buttonNum = buttonNum+1;
}
console.log(correct)
return correct
}


let RIGHT = SetQuiz();

// Judge RIGHT or WRONG and Next Q&A appears (Here is where I got stuck)
const $btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for(let i = 0; i < $btn.length; i++) {
  $btn[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{
  if(RIGHT===$btn[i].textContent){
    console.log("GOOD！");
    SetQuiz();
  }
  else{
    console.log("Not GOOD");
    SetQuiz();
  }})
}
```

Comment: You are on the correct path. Put 2 and 3 in a function, and once you get the answer in step 4, call the function again.

Comment: Thank you Sola. I could put 2 and 3 as follows: let ```RIGHT = SetQuiz();```
But the code below does not work as I expect, which I added to the 1st thread.
// Judge RIGHT or WRONG and Next Q&A appears (Here is where I got stuck)
```const $btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for(let i = 0; i < $btn.length; i++) {
  $btn[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{
  if(RIGHT===$btn[i].textContent){
    console.log("GOOD！");
    SetQuiz();
  }
  else{
    console.log("Not GOOD");
    SetQuiz();
  }})
}```